# fullCalendar.js - unable to drag pass 4:30PM

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When in agenda-mode, I am completely unable to drag the event pass certain time in the day.  Has anybody experienced something similar?  I looked through every single piece of documentation, top to bottom, to no avail.  I'm using Google loaded jQuery and jQuery UI and FullCalendar v1.5.4.

When I drag the event to any other sections - eventDrop function registers and everything works fine, but once I go passed 4:30PM (maybe 5:00PM) the drag function reverts and the event is moved back to where it started.

Comment: Is it somehow related to scroll? Maybe you should provide a live exemple of jour issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was with overriding `line-height` in CSS class `.ui-widget-header`.

If you have it, try removing it, and see if that fixes it.